# Просто объясните что делает метод list()?

Tags: java, list

Сейчас учусь работать с базой данных, с Hibernate.
В интернете нашел примеры для чтения данных из БД, например:

```
String hql = "select * from table_name";
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(hql);
List results = query.list();
```

Так вот вопрос. нигде не могу найти значение метода `list()`, что он в данном случае делает? и как работает?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Первый же результат](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html) по поиску "hibernate query list":

> Queries are executed by calling list()...

Иными словами, запрос выполняется по вызову метода `list()`.

Отличается от `executeUpdate()` тем, что `executeUpdate()` используется при `INSERT`, `DELETE`, `UPDATE` запросах, `list()` же используется при `SELECT` запросе.

Comment: спасибо) я не правильный запрос в поисковике писал) сейчас буду читать)

Comment: @Vorobey.A удачи) если вам был дан правильный ответ, не забудьте отметить его галкой, чтобы другие посетители данной страницы видели правильный ответ.

Answer (score 4):

Метод `SQLQuery.list` возвращает результат запроса в виде `List`, либо `Object []`.